# how to inject custom credential provider without restarting the machine

Tags: registry, restart, credential-providers

I want to inject my custom credential provider without restarting the machine
I have added entry to registry @HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\Credential Providers

But i need to restart the machine so winlogon will call my credential provider.4

Is there any way through which i can achieve this without restarting the machine.

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't be necessary to restart the machine; once you have built the custom credential provider .dll and registered the associated GUID in the registry at the points listed below you should copy the .dll to windows\system32.  Once done if you (e.g.) Start > Switch User then your credential provider should be used

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\Credential Providers\**GUID**]
**@="dllNameWithoutExtension"**


[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\**GUID**]
**@="dllNameWithoutExtension"**
and

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{GUID}\InProcServer32]
**@="dllName.dll"
"ThreadingModel"="Apartment"**
```

The full details are available in the provided examples (try http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4057 - these are for Vista but I've used them happily as a starting point to build something that wors on Win7 / Win8.x as well (just make sure you target the build appropriately- again, instructions are in teh supplied documentation linked to above)